# Philosophers and boys, who are we?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A dissident theologian and a pessimistic philosopher,

A dissident boy and a cheerful cat

Who are we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> Calvin and Hobbes.